# Is there waste of resources in mining as a result of concurrency?

Tags: mining

Suppose there are 10 nodes in network. New block detected. What happen next?
All 10 nodes begin to search for hash for that block simultaneously. One of them found the hash first? What happened with other 9 nodes? Did they just waste resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what happens in the pure PoW world (BTC, ETH as it is now, etc.). All the work they've put in searching for block X is thrown away and a new search start for block X+1.